# Upload Large files using DropZone.js are failing with error code 0

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, dropzone.js

I have created a website for file upload based on https://github.com/vberbenetz/EasyUpload.

This is a Spring Boot project using DropzoneJS and AngularJs with Tomcat as a listener on 8080, uploading the files to a MySQL database.

So far so good...

I can upload and download files just fine, as long as they are just a few KB's in size. I have set the following limits:

```
/* js/fileAppDirectives */

function dropzone() {

return function(scope, element, attrs) {

    var config = {
        url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/upload',
        maxFilesize: 10000,
        paramName: "uploadfile",
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 10,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        autoProcessQueue: false
    };
```

I have also added application.yml with the following:

```
multipart:
max-File-Size:10000MB
max-Request-Size:10000MB
```

However, whenever I try to upload a file larger than 1 MB, I get the error: "Error: Server responded with code 0"

[image: ErrorCode 0]

I don't know how to resolve this.

EDIT:

As suggested [here](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/533110/application-yml), I added this to application.yml.

```
#in bytes
file.max.size: 100000000000
# File size limit
multipart.maxFileSize: 100000Mb   
multipart.maxRequestSize: 200000Mb
```

This however presents me with an [Object] [Object] error

[image]

Still stuck... please help!

Comment: Your problem to this point has nothing to do with mysql. So I removed the tag.

Comment: this is also happening to me, I tried 2.8 Mb and it's get an Internal Server 505 error. have you found answer to this? I've read dropzone is not good in handling large files, but this is so frustrating that using dropzone you can only upload 1Mb below. i'm looking into changing it. but still can't figure out what to replace it with? any advise?

Comment: I have been unable to resolve this issue. I was even in contact with the developer who created "EasyUpload", and was not able to get this resolved. The difference was that I was running this off a Windows Server, where he was running on a Linux box, but that shouldn't matter. I moved on and went with a different solution to work around my problem. (Upload to DattoDrive that syncs the file down to where it needs to go).

Comment: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/701#issuecomment-294105772 - I have added my comment in here, this is an open issue in dropzone and many people are facing it. Just update here if you find it, I am also trying diff. approaches, otherwise have to remove Dropzone!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dropzone v4.4.4+ so you have to set timeout value.

please check  [dropzone config](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-timeout)